# Ansible: Save host names and results of linux command in dictionary format

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I want to save the hosts name and results of linux command in the dictionary format. The problem is I cannot successfully get the dictionary format, and the new line stored in the results.txt file will replace the previous lines.

```
---
- hosts: "{{variable_host | default('lsbxdmss001')}}"
    tasks:
  - name: Check Redhat version for selected servers
    shell:
      cmd: rpm --query redhat-release-server
      warn: False
    register: myshell_output

  - debug: var=myshell_output

  - name: set fact
    set_fact: output = "{{item.0}}:{{item.1}}"
    with_together:
      - groups['{{variable_host}}']
      - "{{myshell_output.stdout}}"
    register: output

  - debug: var=output

  - name: copy the output to results.txt
    copy:
      content: "{{output}}"
      dest: results.txt
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: I am new to ansible. Plz help me!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have four issues:

1. Your dictionary creation seems odd, a dictionary in python is enclosed in curly bracers `{ ... }`
   So you line dictionary

   ```yaml
   "{{item.0}}:{{item.1}}"
   ```

   Should rather be

   ```yaml
   "{{ {item.0: item.1} }}"
   ```
2. Adding to a file, in Ansible, is done via the module [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) rather than the `copy` one.
3. Your loop doesn't really makes sense, as Ansible is already executing each task on all hosts, so the reason you have only one information is also coming from this: you keep on overriding the `output` fact, in your trial to do it.
4. For the same reason as above, instead of your `with_together` loop, you should use the special variable [`inventory_hostname`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables), as this is

   > The inventory name for the ‘current’ host being iterated over in the play

   <sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables*</sup>

So after your `shell` command, here should be the next task:

```yaml
- lineinfile:
    path: results.txt
    line: "{{ {inventory_hostname: myshell_output.stdout} | string }}"
    create: yes
  delegate_to: localhost
```

**Mind that** the [`string`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#string) filter was added in order to convert the dictionary into a string to write it into the file without Ansible issuing a warning.

An example of playbook would be:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - name: Creating a fake shell result
      shell:
        cmd: echo 'Linux Vlersion XYZ {{ inventory_hostname }}'
      register: shell_output

    - lineinfile:
        path: results.txt
        line: "{{ {inventory_hostname: shell_output.stdout} | string }}"
        create: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Which gives the recap:

```
PLAY [all] ******************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Creating a fake shell result] *****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host2]
changed: [host1]

TASK [lineinfile] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1 -> localhost]
changed: [host2 -> localhost]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************
host1                      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2                      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And fill the *results.txt* file with:

```
{'host1': 'Linux Vlersion XYZ host1'}
{'host2': 'Linux Vlersion XYZ host2'}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and reply. It actually helps me a lot. But the variable (variable_host) is a group name of several servers, for example 'Test_servers'. I want to list all the servers belonging to the 'Test_servers' with their corresponding results as dictionary format in the result.txt file. Sorry for my unclear question. Could you do me a favor on that? Since I tried your answer and it shows "Test_server: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: You do not need this because your `hosts` statement already target this host group only. If you end up with `Test_server`, this is most probably because you named it like this in your inventory.

Comment: I use this commanmd to execute ansible: ansible-playbook -i inventory -k playbook.yml --extra-vars "variable_host=Test_servers".
And the format in the inventory file is this:
[Test_server]: 
host1   host2.       Should I change the name of the group? But if I change the group, how should I set the hosts variable?
        What I want in the result should be host1: xxxx   host2: xxxxxx

Comment: So you should use **exactly** what is in the answer. `inventory_hostname`

Comment: I added the explanation of what this is/means in the edited answer

Comment: No, you target your **group** via `hosts: whatever-is-your-group-name` then, Ansible will always loop on all those hosts, even when it delegates the execution to localhost

Comment: Pleasure. If that is the answer to your question, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).